# Date filter is not working on some cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to filter and remove cells which are before a certain date.

There's an issue where after I apply a Date Format some of the dates are not recognised and grouped properly as shown in the image.

Does anyone know what would cause this, and how I'd fix this?

[image: Example]

```
03/11/2016
24/04/2017
18/01/2016 13:25:50
08/05/2017
```

[image: Format]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data?  It looks to me like your data is NOT all formatted as Date type (i.e. if you right click on a cell or column, you can select "**Format Cells**", then use the "**Date**" formatting).

Comment: Hi @jehad i've formatted the columns using Date, as shown in the new image, yet some of the cells do not update.

Comment: Do you still have the filtering problem after the Date formatting?  If you've selected the formatting, all the cells should look similar (i.e. that "18/01/2016 13:25:50" should change to just "18/01/2016").

Comment: @jehad yes, this is after Formatting, they still show this incorrect way.